# How to change color pallete of vega lite heatmap?

Tags: vega-lite

How to change the color scheme in the vega lite heatmap

I tried changing the range scheme to different values, but the color not changing

[image]

https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoJFEwMdaEAEFFIHACc4ymmedXbSqGwazMaAEYAZgBfBRMzC0EPO0dnV0x3dAAhO29ff1QABjCI80t0T3snFzdlKwBhNJ8-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

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [scheme](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoJFEwMdaEAEFFIHACc4ymmedXbSqGwazMaAEYAZgBfBRMzC0EPO0dnV0x3dAAhO29ff1QABjCI80t0T3snFzdlKwBhNJ8-NBzwkFN86JTYkoSkm2qMutzGyIKQVKU40sTy1q8azID6vKirYeL4ssru2tQANj6mhfQqkfbVwvXMuf7mtcOV8cXT3obdwYPlsc6X9I2AThCAXTD7EgHEgEAZUMYQLIQXArDAaGQYMIEf4lBA4II4GYrDg2DRan8lMgHABrNCgTAATxwMPQTixqMwDjYxLgAHUaMp6GgAEwAuCybwuWRkMkgCmigBmNHREwuCyUlOpVlkbAQeMsAIAHpLpYJZaMOuUFVSaZDVerogCpYIWqApTKrJ8USBFaaAI4WPx0NQ0Uh2aA6GmgLiIU1QNTkNgOCncrJMEAhAEQRnMoMgbyyFyYdjyTSA4EIWHwxHF52IHCUtASnRopTaXSmpiCUykgH1vRoWQMG0Atg4Ux0cV5jNZnOi-sFosIpFYOztmkBNs6DvZShiXsOZRwByikd0Md5icgqcl5Fz5cLpcN3oAjNSkV5gMY0VMJCZgAKSGUQrIAElZLI251Eor4fl+P4APIMIkO7ZG20oAO6ismcA4GgAAs9SNJqNBgqAyiqkgeJVjWcCJiEQA) for the fill scale.

```json
    "fill": {
        "field": "count",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "scale": {
            "scheme": "category20b"
        }
    },
```

You could also provide a [color range](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoJFEwMdaEAEFFIHACc4ymmedXbSqGwazMaAEYAZgBfBRMzC0EPO0dnV0x3dAAhO29ff1QABjCI80t0T3snFzdlKwBhNJ8-NBzwkFN86JTYkoSkm2qMutzGyIKQVKU40sTy1q8azID6vKirYeL4ssru2tQANj6mhfQqkfbVwvXMuf7mtcOV8cXT3obdwYPlsc6X9I2AThCAXTD7EgHEgEAZUMYQLIQXArDAaGQYMIEf4lBA4II4GYrDg2DRan8lMgHABrNCgTAATxwMPQTixqMwDjYxLgAHUaMp6GgAEwAuCybwuWRkMkgCmigBmNHREwuCyUlOpVlkbAQeMsAIAHpLpYJZaMOuUFVSaZDVerogCpYIWqApTKrJ8USBFaaAI4WPx0NQ0Uh2aA6GmgYHCmmGEAQGiCUgOWIMBw4DF2RKWJRMXQw-4AiCM5lBkDeWQuTDseSaQHAhCw+GImvOxA4SloCU6NFKbQZqzp0ykgEdvRoWQMG0Atg4Ux0cXlwvF0ui8eV6sIpFYOz9mkBPs6AfZShiUcOZRwWPTuSzuTzoEgpe15Fr7cbred7IhAGFqUi8sBpPlphIIsAApIMoQpkAAkrIsjHnUab-soQEgXiZAAPIMIkJ71CAxDSgA7qKOZwDgaAACyYUgmo0GCoDKKqSB4s2rZwK+IRAA) instead of a preset scheme.

```json
    "fill": {
        "field": "count",
        "type": "quantitative",
        "scale": {
            "range": [
                "silver",
                "purple",
                "teal",
                "blue"
            ]
        }
    },
```